# What is the fastest way of squaring a $2 \times 2$ matrix?

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I know about the [Strassen algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) in general, however, it is trivial that a $2 \times 2$ matrix can be squared using $5$(orginally wrote $6$) multiplications. But can we do better? Please assume that multiplication is very expensive.

---

Edit: I missed that $5$ multiplications can be done. But the question is then, why not $4$? This is what we have so far:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d\\
\end{pmatrix} ^ 2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a^2 +bc & b(a + d)\\
c(a+d) & bc +d^2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Algorithm:

```
P = b*c
S = a+d
M[0] = P + a*a
M[1] = b*S
M[2] = c*S
M[3] = P + d*d
```

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: The fact that multiplication is very expansive (compared to addition) could have been true before, but now it is (almost) no longer the case (you have for example a "muladd" operator on certain processors).

Comment: @JeanMarie: advances in hardware haven't affected asymptotic performance. And that is relevant to those who need to work with very high precision real arithmetic or with arbitrary size integer arithmetic.

Comment: For the 2x2 case, square it by hand and it's straightforward to write it using only $5$ multiplications.